# Alternative to rsync for file level cloning?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, linux-mint, data-transfer, clonezilla, disk-cloning

I have 500gb of files that I want to copy to a temporary drive and then back.

I would like to be able to do this as fast as possible.

I checked out doing a block level clone, which is nice and fast (a **lot** of my files are very small so using rsync takes ages), however I can't copy between two different partition types (with *CloneZilla* anyway) which I need to be able to do.

So how can I copy a bunch of data fast? I'd be happy to purchase a clonezilla alternative if it can copy between different partition types.

Running Mint and Snow Leopard.

Comment: Is this an external or internal HDD? If it's an external HDD, a) can it be installed interenally, and b) does it have eSATA?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered `tar` of all things?  Sounds silly, I know.  Try this:

```
$ cd /path/to/my/source/files
$ tar -cf - . | tar -xvf - -C /path/to/my/destination/files
```

It should perform surprisingly well with lots of small files - better than `rsync` certainly.

Comment: Thanks for that :) I left it for 8 hours and sadly it still hadn't finished though, and I could've run CloneZilla twice in that time. Are there any cloning programs which support going from NTFS->HFS?

Comment: THat long could imply you have a broken filesystem.  Consider running Disk Uility.

Answer (score 0):

With current tools like Partclone and Partimage, both used by CloneZilla, it isn't possible to copy between two different file system formats on a block level.

Instead you could try the ditto command in Leopard:

```
$ ditto source destination
```

But your milage may vary as basic commands like copying files are usually faster on Linux.